# Laravel request validation error

Tags: laravel, validation, controller

Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given, called in app\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController.php on line 23

It doesn't work here

[Registration Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50TTg.png)

but at the same time works fine in another controller

[AuthController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5ZJQ.png)

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're passing your validation rules to the `request()` helper function and not as the 2nd param to `$this->validate()`

You can still use the `request()` helper function but you just need to do:

```
$this->validate(request(), [
    'name'     => 'required',
    'email'    => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'password|confirmed', //<-- Is the password rule something you've created?!?
]);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`function store()`should be `function store(Request $request)` if you want to use the request. However [@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) is right: please learn to ask your questions better.

Comment: I've struggled with formulating this particular question, I agree it wasn't clear one. I've found my mistake, should've past request helper as the first argument to validate and an array of fields to be validated as the second argument.